# How to render the index view, from inside a view in ruby-on-rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, web-applications, view, rendering

I'm trying to render a the index view inside my ruby-on-rails application. How do a I render the index view, from inside a view passing an array of things to display? Using the link_to.

I do not want to re-route to the controller, I just want to link_to a view passing it the variables it needs, how can I do this? 
EDIT: 
I am trying to create a page type functionality in the index of my article model. So I have around 400 articles for example, and when the index action in the article controller is called, it of course renders the index view which is calling a partial for each article in the '@articles array' passed on by article controller's index action.

So in the view, I'm trying to do something like:

```
    <% count = 0 %>
    <% @articles.each do |article| %>
      <% if count <10 %>
        <%= render partial: 'index_articles', locals: {article: article} %>
        <% count = count + 1 %>
      <% end %>
    <% end %>
    <% @articles = @articles.drop(10) %>
    <% if @articles.any? %>
      <%= link_to "Next", 'articles', locals: {@articles => @articles} %>
    <% end %>
```

Thank you in advanced for all of your help.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to use the [`render` command](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#rendering-an-action-s-view), *probably* with a [partial](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-partials):

```
<%= render "controller/index", collection: ["your", "array"], as: :object_name %>
```

You will *have* to call a controller action to generate this. You cannot simply load it on your screen, unless it was preloaded inside your javascript for something:

```
#View
<%= link_to "Index", controllers_path(ids: ["1","2"]), remote: true %>

#app/controllers/your_controller.rb
class YourController < ApplicationController
   def index
      @posts = request.xhr? Post.find(params[:ids]) : Post.all
      respond_to do |format|
         format.js  #-> app/views/controller/index.js.erb
         format.html
      end
   end
end

#app/views/controller/index.js.erb
$(".element").html("<%=j render 'index' %>");
```

There are several issues with this approach...

---

**Flow**

First of all, your *flow* of your app should be as structured as possible.

In short, if you're calling the `index` view inside another action, it's *not* the index view any more.

What you should look at is how to use a partial in your app:

```
#app/controller/views/_partial.html.erb
<%= post.title %>
```

This way, you can adapt your `index` view and your other page to use the partial in their respective action layouts:

```
#app/controller/views/index.html.erb
<%= render "partial", collection: @posts, as: :post %>
```

This will allow you to "reuse" code much in the way you want. This will be much more appropriate than trying to invoke other action/views.

-

**Resources**

Secondly, you'll want to look at how your app functions.

Your *index* view is meant to show all the items for a particular object. Whilst you're free to change this as you want, the fact remains that you have to k[eep some structure](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#resources-on-the-web).

[image]

You should read up on the routes for your actions, and how they're meant to work in your application. This will give you some perspective on the `resourceful` nature of Rails routes, and how you'll have to call specific routes with specific actions.

Comment: Hello, thank you for your reply. However, I understand the routes of actions and I'm not trying to remove how this basic functionality works. I'm trying (without the use of a gem) to basically create a set of pages. For example, I have around 400 articles, and I want to index them in no more than 10 per page. So I already have a partial (to display each article), so views/articles/index.html.erb is trying to display 10 articles at a time, then remove those 10 articles from the articles, then when somebody clicks next, I'd like to display this new list of articles with 10 less on a new page.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is probably that the file needs to be named _index.html.erb. You can have another file named index.html.erb which just renders _index.html.erb.

If you need a full guide on using AJAX, look up the railscast. If you're not using AJAX and you just want to render it, then you don't use link_to. You just do <%= render :index %>.

Comment: I already have this going, I know how to do basic rails type things. I'm trying print a specific subset of a particular model. So using the index, will build a list of all active records of this model, now I want to render them, for example 20 at a time. So do 20, then the user clicks next, and another 20 appear. It's a page type functionality.

Comment: And I already know how to render a partial view, I want a link_to, to render another view.